# Convert Base 64 string to bytes []

Tags: angularjs, base64

I'm getting this error when converting a base 64 string to byte array :

The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

This is my base 64 string:

```
data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;base64,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
```

Comment: `data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;base64,` isn't base 64. Are you trying to convert the whole string or just the base64 part. What code are you using for the conversion?

Comment: In decodes fine after removing this part.